# Models and Data Access Objects, which should be passed and what should be passed

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, data-access-layer

I'm trying to make my models ignorant of sql codes and the connection, so I am trying to implement a so called "data access object" / "dao".

My models represent tables in the database, and its properties to db fields like this for example a loginModel

```
class LoginModel {

   private $user;
   private $pass;
   private $salt;
   private $ip;
   private $agent;

   // getters and setters e.g.
   public function getUser() {
       return $this->user;
   }
   public function setUser($user) {
       $this->user = $user;
   }
   // or for example magic methods -> just for example

   public function __get($key) {
       return $this->$key;
   }

   public function __set($key, $value) {
       $this->$key = $value;
   }

}
```

In my development, which I think I am doing the wrong thing, in my view or in my controller, I am doing this:

```
$loginModel = new LoginModel();
$loginModel->setUser('$_POST["user"]');
$loginDAO = new LoginDAO($loginModel);
echo $loginDAO->getResults();
```

Is is the proper way to do this? Or should I read the process the `POST` variables first in the DAO and then set the properties of the model?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to further abstract that into different scenarios involving multiple types of storage, you may want to check out the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

edit: looked at your question again, realized you didnt need half that answer but here's what i removed:

---

The way you design your models could be making things a little confusing. Try designing your models as objects instead of processes.

The process of a login would be handled by a controller, whereas a model would be responsible for getting things from a database. This would mean you use your models inside the controllers as a way to complete a task.